# Scroll event listener resets scroll to top whenever I try to scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

so I ran into this very odd javascript issue. Everything was working fine and my scroll event listener would trigger properly. Now though, after changing some stuff around, it appears to be failing.

Specifically, whenever I try to scroll I am immediately set back to the top again. There is no error in the console, so I presume it's not a syntax error of any sort. Here's my JS snippet:

```js
var header = document.querySelector('.Header');
var content = document.querySelector('.Hero__content');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  console.log("Added listener.");
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 && !header.classList.contains('Header--fixed')) {
    console.log("Scrolled below 300.");
    header.classList.add('Header--fixed');
    header.classList.remove('Header--inHero');
  } else if (document.body.scrollTop = 0 && header.classList.contains('Header--fixed')) {
    console.log("Scrolled to top.");
    header.classList.remove('Header--fixed');
    header.classList.add('Header--inHero');
  }
});
```

I have added some console.log() statements to see what was happening. The results of that are that on load nothing is logged. When I try to scroll it keeps logging "Added listener", so the first console.log() there. It logs it many times per scroll (though it should be noted I scroll with a trackpad, so that might have something to do with the amount of times it's triggered).

The general class modifying behavior, by the way, is retained. When I scroll hard enough and get below my 300px marker (document.body.scrollTop > 300) the class is added and the other class is removed. When at the top again the else if method is not triggered however.

The script is at the end of my HTML file before the closing body tag. It is followed by two further scripts, which I will provide you in order:

main.js contains the Google Web Starter kit default JS file, which is a self invoking function doing some offline caching work. This file was not modified.  It's available as a whole [on GitHub](https://github.com/google/web-starter-kit/blob/master/app/scripts/main.js), that way I don't have to copy the whole thing here.

The other one is a Google Analytics snippet, it's copied directly from Google.

The order is:

1. Final elements of body tag
2. My snippet inline using script tags
3. main.js from Google
4. Google Analytics snippet

The expected behavior is no scrolling interference and proper class modification, the actual behavior is odd scrolling resets on every attempt to scroll.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears I removed a < symbol, which made <= 0 into = 0. This condition would always be true at the beginning so it would always reset the class right back.